# Testing blender project

Tags: python

I am developing a blender project which renders objects on a scene. I need to achieve sufficient test coverage, but am having trouble testing due to lack of knowledge.
We're running blender 2.76 from a docker image and run our files on the image. We need testing to be part of git pipeline and we're using pytest.

I can't run the test files on docker because there is no pytest on the image. I can't run it on my machine since I don't have the modules, and they wouldn't run in the pipeline either.

What approach could I take to run tests in the pipeline (or even my own machine) while using blender? Is it even possible?

Edit: This isn't entirely related to blender, more blender integration with python.

```
 def set_random_orientation(self, obj):
        obj.rotation_euler[0] = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=360) * math.pi / 180
        obj.rotation_euler[1] = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=360) * math.pi / 180
        obj.rotation_euler[2] = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=360) * math.pi / 180
```

Example of a function that I want to test. I'm having trouble loading the Object without blender running, so not sure how to gain access to those classes without it being run on an image, which I think is impossible.

Comment: Please provide a clear description of what you're trying to do with Blender and what doesn't work. Is the issue that the pytest module isn't available in Blender 2.76? How and what exactly are you trying to test and how does this relate to Blender?

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: That example function doesn't make sense outside of Blender since you're using objects of `bpy.types.Object`. Hence you either need to run it in Blender (with or without GUI) or as a Python module ([build Blender as a Python module](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Other/BlenderAsPyModule))?